# Translate NSCalendar.weekdaySymbols index to NSDateComponents.weekday

Tags: ios, nscalendar

I'm writing a feature of my iOS app that involves scheduling weekly repeating local notifications on particular days of the week. I'd like to use the [`NSCalendar`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscalendar) APIs properly so I don't assume things I shouldn't. But I don't see any property on `NSCalendar` about how many days there are in a week.

I'm displaying days of the week using [`weekdaySymbols`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscalendar/1412939-weekdaysymbols), and letting the user choose which days they want notifications on. Then I'm scheduling local notifications based on that.

The real question is: **How do I translate a day's index in `weekdaySymbols` into the value I give to `NSDateComponents` for `weekday`?**

Comment: It depends on the calendar identifier. A `gregorian` calendar has always 7 days in a week.

Comment: @vadian what's a calendar that doesn't? And what is the best way to tell if the device is set to one of those calendars?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with other calendars than the gregorian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a simplification, but you can think of days of the week as belonging to the Gregorian calendar, independent of what calendar is actually in use. Those calendars largely govern day/month/year arithmetic, with the days of the week proceeding independently of the particulars of each calendar's number and length of months.

If you accept that as a given, then you just need to correct for the off-by-one difference between a calendar's `weekdaySymbols` (indexed from 0 to 6) and `NSDateComponents.weekday` (a value from 1 to 7).

```
extension DateComponents {     // NSDateComponents in Swift < 3
    func weekdaySymbol(in calendar: Calendar) -> String? {
        guard let weekday = self.weekday else { return nil }
        return calendar.weekdaySymbols[weekday - 1]
    }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic. Did you mean to make `weekday` an argument to `func weekdaySymbol`?

Comment: No, it's a property of `DateComponents`—I'll add `self` so it's more clear.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I should have caught that - the property is an integral part of my question, after all. But I don't do much in swift yet and I'm not used to referring to properties without `self`.